Does vehicle AC refrigerant like R-134a expire?
I have a can of R-134a, but it's been sitting there for several years. Now that my car's refrigerant is low. I'm hoping to recharge the car. Do I need to get new refrigerants or I can use the old one? Thanks!

This probably really belongs here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement.

Does not expire. Of course, if you don't fix the leak in the car, it leaks out again.

I will note that the cans can deteriorate and release the refrigerant slowly over time.  But you're right—they don't really "expire."

The good and the bad of typical refrigerants ("Freon") is that they basically last forever. That is great inside a refrigerator or air conditioner or similar device - you want a chemical that doesn't break down even over many thousands of thermal cycles under high pressure, etc. and that don't react at all with any of the pipes, valves, etc. in a typical system.
But that is bad for the environment when the gas escapes. Many refrigerants are considered very potent greenhouse gases because they don't break down easily in normal atmospheric conditions.
The end result is that except for leaking out from a corroded container, and that corrosion is more likely to be from the outside (rusting out from humidity in the air, etc.) than the inside. If it still has refrigerant under pressure, you can use it.
Of course, you must make sure you use the correct refrigerant. Different refrigerants have different thermal and other properties. Using the wrong type of refrigerant (e.g., something new that is better for the environment in an old system that was not designed for it) can lead to serious equipment damage.
